# Why doesn't the send_email function show up in my console?

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I made a basic Django form and implemented that into my HTML.  In my views.py, I am trying to send an email out, and I know even if I can't send the email, I should still see a successful POST submission and email detail in terminal.  However, the page simply refreshes and nothing happens.

views.py snippet:

```python
def ticket(request, room_name):

form_class = TicketForm

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = TicketForm()

    else:
        form = TicketForm(request.POST)

        # validating and cleaning data
        if form.is_valid():
            type_of_issue = form.cleaned_data['type_of_issue']
            #a lot of fields are cleaned, irrelevant to question

            try:
                send_mail("Issue/Feedback for Room " + room_name, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')

            return redirect('index') #index is my homepage separate from my form/ticket page

     return render(request, 'ticket.html', context={'room_name': room_name, 'room': room, 'form': form_class, })
```

ticket.html (where my form is located) snippet:

```html
<form id="ticket-border" class="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!--a lot of form data goes here, irrelevant to question-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

settings.py snippet that has to do with sending email

```python
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'notmyrealpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I've looked at many examples and YouTube videos online, but I seem to be missing why nothing shows up on my console after submitting.  The page simply refreshes after hitting submit.  It shouldn't be going into my if == GET statement, but I checked that it isn't by changing the criteria and sending it somewhere else, which it didn't do.

Can a fresh pair of eyes help me see the problem?

Edit: Forgot to add, I've also tried adding either

```html
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

or

```html
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

into my settings.py, but it makes no difference.  The page still refreshes and nothing shows up in my console or inbox.

Added TicketForm upon request:

```html
class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    type_of_issue = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ISSUE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(), required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'first-name', 'type': 'text', 'name': 'first-name', 'maxlength': '50', 'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'last-name', 'type': 'text', 'name': 'last-name', 'maxlength': '50', 'placeholder': 'Last name'}))
    email_address = forms.EmailField(required=False, widget=forms.EmailInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'email', 'id': 'email', 'name': 'email', 'placeholder': 'Email address'}))
    feedback_or_further_details = forms.CharField(
        required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5', 'name': 'additional-details', 'placeholder': 'Please enter additional details or your feedback here.'}))
    affiliation = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=AFFILIATION_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True)
```

Comment: Obviously your form is not valid and `form.is_valid()` returns `False`. Edit your question to include the source code for `TicketForm` too.

Comment: I edited to add source code for TicketForm.  Why doesn't form.is_valid() return True?  It seems like it should.